# How do I set wrap a value into a `Maybe` when chaining functions?

Tags: haskell, option-type

I have a chaining of functors and I need at some point to wrap my value in a `Maybe`:

```
module Funct where 
(>>?) :: Maybe a -> (a -> Maybe b) -> Maybe b
(Just a) >>? f = f a
Nothing >>? _ = Nothing


f1 :: Int -> Maybe Bool
f1 a = if a > 2 then Just (a `mod` 2 == 0)  else Nothing

f2 :: Bool ->  Char
f2 b = if b then 'a' else 'b'

f3 :: Char -> Maybe Int
f3 c = if c == 'a' then Just 1 else Nothing

fm :: Int -> Maybe Int
fm x = f1 x >>? f2  >>? f3
                 ^ 
                 Is there a reverse method for fmap particular for Maybe 
                 or do I have to implement it?
```

**Implemented**

```
myWrapper :: Char->Maybe Char
myWrapper c = Just c

fm x = f1 x >>? myWrapper . f2 >>? f3  -- is there any built in way more concise?
```

I am asking because when chaining I suppose you would need wrappers for other monads too like `Either`.

Comment: `myWrapper` is exactly  `return`, just as `>>?` is exactly `>>=`.

Comment: But `return` works for the `IO` monad i want something that works for `Maybe`.

Comment: `return` (definitionally) works for _any_ monad, including `Maybe` and `Either a`.

Comment: And `pure` instead of `return` works as well for any `Applicative`, including `Maybe`.

Comment: You *do* need wrappers for each monad, but tha't

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> (is there any built in way more concise?)

Sure:

```
myWrapper = Just
```

Or inline:

```
fm x= f1 x>>? Just . f2 >>? f3
```

Data constructors can be viewed as plain functions, so you can compose them with other functions.

Comment: Happy b-day, arrowd! =D

Comment: Who's there? ._.

Answer (score 5):

There is [`(<&>) = flip fmap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Functor.html#v:-60--38--62-), that has the same precedence as `(>>=)`:

```
fm x = f1 x <&> f2 >>= f3
```

Answer (score 2):

> I am asking because when chaining I suppose you would need wrappers for other monads too like Either.

Correct. Each type constructor like `Maybe` and `Either` needs its own definition for things like `>>=` and `return`, but that's exactly what an instance of a typeclass is: the definitions of the typeclass's methods specialized for a particular type constructor. For example,

```
class Monad m where
    return :: a -> m a
    (>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b

instance Monad Maybe where
    return = Just
    Nothing >>= _ = Nothing
    (Just x) >>= f = f x

-- This looks similar to the Maybe instance because in some sense,
-- Maybe is just a special case of Either: Maybe ~ Either ()
instance Monad (Either a) where
    return = Right
    (Left x) >>= _ = Left x
    (Right x) >>= f = f x
```

Your `fm` function can then be written in a way that works for *any* monad, not just `Maybe`:

```
fm :: Maybe m => Int -> m Int
fm x = f1 x >>= return . f2  >>= f3
```